# Django REST Framework TokenAuthentication to authenticate in Django generally

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We're using `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` to authenticate API users in Django REST Framework using an access token.

Is there a way to use this same class to authenticate users for Django generally?

I've tried adding it straight in to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` but it doesn't work:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",

    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

Is there a quick way to do this or do I need to write a custom authentication backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django REST framework authentication and permission classes require the use of Django REST framework views, as the authentication is done on the view level <sup>[1]</sup>. This is different from Django authentication backends, where the authentication is done through the middleware.

> Is there a way to use this same class to authenticate users for Django generally?

No, Django REST framework authentication backends are distinctly separate from Django authentication backends, and the reverse is *technically* true <sup>[2]</sup>.

<sub>[1]: There has been discussion of moving this to the middleware level, but this is not currently planned.</sub>
<sub>[2]: Django authentication backends can be used through `SessionAuthentication` and other comparable DRF backends.</sub>

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. Presumably however one could create a custom authentication backend using something like `user = Token.objects.get(token=token_from_request_header).user' to get the user?

Comment: Yes, DRF backends are [not much different](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/35efbe41abcff15ea2f60096aaa95bd41f2532a3/rest_framework/authentication.py#L154-L167) from Django backends, you should just need to implement a few extra methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *SessionAuthentication*.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Use Django's session framework for authentication.
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ....
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

Comment: `SessionAuthentication` doesn't allow users to authenticate with a Django Rest Framework token, does it?  Just tested, and Django still thinks the user is unauthenticated...

Comment: Have you kept TokenAuthentication after SessionAuthentication?

Comment: I have - I'm using `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication,'
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

)`